# Magento 2: How many options do I have to use with addFieldToFilter?

Tags: magento2, module, collection, model, sql

What out-of-the-box logical conditions can I use with the `addFieldToFilter` method?

```
$this->addFieldToFilter();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method has two parameters.

```
public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition)
```

If **$condition** integer or string - exact value will be filtered ('eq' condition)

If **$condition** is an array - one of the following structures is expected:

```
["from" => $fromValue, "to" => $toValue]
["eq" => $equalValue]
["neq" => $notEqualValue]
["like" => $likeValue]
["in" => [$inValues]]
["nin" => [$notInValues]]
["notnull" => $valueIsNotNull]
["null" => $valueIsNull]
["moreq" => $moreOrEqualValue]
["gt" => $greaterValue]
["lt" => $lessValue]
["gteq" => $greaterOrEqualValue]
["lteq" => $lessOrEqualValue]
["finset" => $valueInSet]
```

**If not matched** - sequential parallel arrays are expected and OR conditions
will be built using above mentioned structure.

**Example:**

```
$field = ['age', 'name'];
$condition = [42, ['like' => 'Mage']];
```

The above would find where age equal to **42** OR name like **%Mage%**.

Reference [here](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1249).